# Rails - How can I assign a user moderator privileges?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to assign a user moderator privileges by entering their email address in a form. I am currently able assign moderator status to a user through the rails console but I'm not sure of how to do this on the actual page.

My current set up is as follows:
There are multiple Coin pages. A User can moderate more than one Coin page, but a Coin page can have only one moderator. So right now the associations are set up as:

Coin:

```
belongs_to :moderator, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => "moderator_id"
```

User:

```
has_many :moderated_coins, class_name: "Coin", :foreign_key => "moderator_id"
```

Then in the console, I am able to assign moderator status with

```
@coin.moderator = @user
```

What I would like to do is have a form on the Coin page where an admin user can enter some user's email address, then it will find the user and set @user.moderator to true.

so in my (coin) show.html.erb, I would like to have something like

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  # enter a user's email in form -> get user id
  # user.moderator = true
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this and would appreciate some assistance.

coin.rb

```
class Coin < ApplicationRecord
  validates :currency_name, presence: true
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
  belongs_to :moderator, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => "moderator_id",  optional: true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :moderated_coins, class_name: "Coin", :foreign_key => "moderator_id"

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable, authentication_keys: [:login]

  validates :username, presence: :true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates_format_of :username, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/, :multiline => true
  validate :validate_username

  def validate_username
    if User.where(email: username).exists?
      errors.add(:username, :invalid)
    end
  end

  def login=(login)
    @login = login
  end

  def login
    @login || self.username || self.email
  end

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    elsif conditions.has_key?(:username) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
      where(conditions.to_h).first
    end
  end
end
```

coins_controller.rb

```
class CoinsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource param_method: :question_params
  before_action :find_coin, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :create, :show]

  def index      
    @search = Coin.ransack(params[:q])
    @coins = @search.result(distinct: true)
  end

  def new
    @coin = Coin.new
  end

  def create
    @coin = Coin.new(coin_params)
    if @coin.save!
      flash[:success] = "Coin created"
      redirect_to @coin
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show  
    @coin = Coin.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    authorize! :update, @coin
  end

  def update
    if @coin.update(coin_params)
      redirect_to @coin
    else
      render 'edit'
    end     
  end

  def destroy
    Coin.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to coins_url
  end

  def get_moderator
    if @coin.moderator
      @coin.moderator
    end
  end

  private

    def coin_params
      params.require(:coin).permit( :currency_name, :currency_abbrev, :working_product, :founder, :mineable, :moderator_id, genre_ids:[])
    end

    def find_coin
      @coin = Coin.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.xml { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
end
```

From schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.string "wallet"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.boolean "moderator", default: false
    t.decimal "currentbalance", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.decimal "payout_to_date", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.text "bio"
    t.string "link1"
    t.string "link2"
    t.string "link3"
    t.string "link4"
    t.string "link5"
    t.string "name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end


    create_table "coins", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string "link_name"
      t.string "currency_name"
      t.string "currency_abbrev"
      t.float "volume_usd"
      t.float "volume_btc"
      t.string "picture"
      t.text "question1"
      t.text "question2"
      t.text "question3"
      t.text "question4"
      t.text "question5"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      t.string "permalink"
      t.string "genre"
      t.integer "moderator_id"
      t.boolean "accepted", default: false
      t.datetime "accepted_at"
      t.integer "genre_id"
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using a custom attribute for the moderator's email, on the Coin model. What I mean by custom attribute is just adding a `attr_accessor :moderator_email` to your `Coin` model, that is not linked to any database column, but only used temporary to retrieve the correct user. For example:

```
class Coin < ApplicationRecord

  # Add the following
  attr_accessor :moderator_email

  before_save do
    if moderator_email.present?
      self.moderator = User.find_by_email(moderator_email) # Tip: use find_by_email! (with the !) if you want the save cancelled when email is not found
    end
  end
end
```

With that in place, you should be able to add a `<%= f.text_field :moderator_email %>` to your form.

Also, don't forget to add `:moderator_email` to your `coin_params` in the controller. But remember, if you don't want all users to be able to update this, you need to add some extra checks to validate this. I would adjust the `coin_params` method to look like this:

```
  def coin_params
    if current_user.try(:admin?)
      params.require(:coin).permit( :moderator_email, :currency_name, :currency_abbrev, :working_product, :founder, :mineable, :moderator_id, genre_ids:[])
    else
      params.require(:coin).permit( :currency_name, :currency_abbrev, :working_product, :founder, :mineable, :moderator_id, genre_ids:[])
    end
  end
```

Comment: One more question, your method works except when I redirect to the main page after making an update (as the moderator), the moderator status is removed and I have to assign it again. Any idea of why this might happen? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I were to guess, I might think that you have a form field for the :moderator_id and that it is being submitted as nil. If that is the case, you can simply remove that field (also from coin_params) since it is being handled by the moderator_email attribute.